# Returning a class instead of void from port's method

Tags: java, soap, cxf, soap-client, webservice-client

I am a beginner in SOAP services. I have a use-case to consume some SOAP methods. Therefore, for that, I have coded a client to get some service port's methods data.

Currently, I realized from the WSDL that I imported, the specific service methods have a void return type. However, I would like to have  return port methods. For example:

This is the current behaviour from the WSDL:

```
SomeService ss = new SomeService();
ProxyPort port = ss.getPort();
port.IdentifyBaggage(identifyBaggageIndicators,
                bagTagDetailsTopLevel, baggageGroupInfo, flightDetailsResponse, quantityDetails, dummySegment);
```

However, the behaviour that I want is :

```
SomeService ss = new SomeService();
ProxyPort port = ss.getPort();
BaggageReply reply= port.IdentifyBaggage(identifyBaggageIndicators,
                bagTagDetailsTopLevel, baggageGroupInfo, flightDetailsResponse, quantityDetails, dummySegment);
```

I tried adding the return type in SEI but it gives me:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to bla.bla.bla.BaggageReply    at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.IdentifyBaggage(Unknown Source)

The SEI looks something like this:

```
/**
    * @param identifyBaggageIndicators
    * @param bagTagDetails
    * @param baggageGroupInfo
    * @param routingDetails
    * @param historicalDays
    * @param dummy
    */
   @WebMethod(operationName = "IdentifyBaggage", action = "http://webservices.amadeus.com/endpoint1")
   @RequestWrapper(localName = "IdentifyBaggage", targetNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/endpoint1", className = "com.amadeus.xml.bla_bla.IdentifyBaggage")
   @ResponseWrapper(localName = "BaggageReply", targetNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/endpoint2", className = "com.amadeus.xml.bla1_bla1.BaggageReply")
   public void dcsbagIdentifyBaggage(
       @WebParam(name = "identifyBaggageIndicators", targetNamespace = "http://some.host.com/endpoint1")
       List<StatusTypeI> identifyBaggageIndicators,
       @WebParam(name = "bagTagDetails", targetNamespace = "http://some.host.com/endpoint1")
       BaggageInformationTypeI bagTagDetails,
       @WebParam(name = "baggageGroupInfo", targetNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/endpoint1")
       IdentifyBaggage.BaggageGroupInfo baggageGroupInfo,
       @WebParam(name = "routingDetails", targetNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/endpoint1")
       FlightDetailsResponseType routingDetails,
       @WebParam(name = "historicalDays", targetNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/endpoint1")
       NumberOfUnitsType historicalDays,
       @WebParam(name = "dummy", targetNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/endpoint2", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
               com.amadeus.xml.bla_bla.DummySegmentTypeI dummy);
```

What could be the way to add the return type?

Comment: Confusing description. How can `void` be return type of the method if its return type is `DCSBAGBaggageReply`?

Comment: Still could not find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing Contract first (you have a WSDL as a starting point) SOAP client development.

**You have to connect somewhere and the service is "static" (could not be changed)**

1, If the SOAP service cannot be changed (e.g. because it is not yours) and the WSDL you have is proper (made out of the running service), you could not do that.

2, If the WSDL you have is obsolete and you are seeing return types that are not there in the WSDL, simply get the new WSDL, generate another client classes and use them.

**You have to connect to a service that is yours (both the client side and the server side is developed by you)**

This is the more interesting part, and here we have two different ways:

**1, Contract first web service development (I prefer this)**

You made a WSDL from scratch with every operation and complextype.
You have to create a new *BaggageReply* complextype and modify the operation similarly to this (random wsdl sample):

```
    <message name="GetLastTradePriceInput">
        <part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePriceRequest"/>
    </message>

    <message name="GetLastTradePriceOutput">
        <part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePrice"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="StockQuotePortType">
        <operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
           <input message="tns:GetLastTradePriceInput"/>
           <output message="tns:GetLastTradePriceOutput"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
```

The key is the <output> and the defined class (in the message attribute of the output tag).
Then regenerate the client and the server side, update the serverimpl, and implement the client properly.

**2, code first development (you have started to write your own java classes)**

In this case, you are a skilled developer who knows very well how to do this :)
Assuming that you have the server side code, I would copy the input class (*com.amadeus.xml.bla_bla.IdentifyBaggage*) rename it to the output class and update the localName and the namespace of the QName, the members, setters/getters etc. and replace the void return value of the operation to this class.
The last thing is to update the operation or webmethod to return a *BaggageReply* at the end.
Of course, your client has to be modified too to make something with this reply.